# Hover over tag "button" should display Interesting/Ignore text everywhere

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

If you visit a Tag Wiki page ([nginx example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx)), hovering over any of the tags within a question will bring up a sub-menu allowing you to add the tag to Interesting/Ignore. I think any tag displayed anywhere should have this ability.

Answer (score 2):

Completed a while back with [Tag Favorites and Tag Subscriptions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/)

Comment: I disagree; while you can "subscribe" to a tag, you cannot add it to interesting/ignore. That was my primary request.

**EDIT** I noticed that clicking the star will add it to interesting, but there's still no "easy" way to ignore it.

Comment: @waffles I would also say that this is only partially completed:  I know this is a monor annoyance, but since it can be difficult  to copy/paste a tag that is in the middle of a group of tags, an ability to "ignore" at tag from the sub-menu would be greatly appreciated.  Could you remove the "completed" tag, or, I will be glad to start another feature-request if you think that would be better.